# CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH not working on specific device

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

I have the following method to start a camera preview and prepare a MediaRecorder

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_preview)
    //mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultCameraInstance();

    if(Utils.hasFrontCamera())
        mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    else
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    // We need to make sure that our preview and recording video size are supported by the
    // camera. Query camera to find all the sizes and choose the optimal size given the
    // dimensions of our preview surface.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes,
            mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight());


    // Use the same size for recording profile.
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    profile.audioChannels = 2;
//  profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
//  profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;

    Log.e("Resolution ",profile.videoFrameWidth + " - "+profile.videoFrameHeight);
    //profile.videoBitRate = 3000000;
    //profile.videoFrameRate = 24;

    // likewise for the camera object itself.
    parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    try {
        // Requires API level 11+, For backward compatibility use {@link setPreviewDisplay}
        // with {@link SurfaceView}
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());

        if (Utils.isModeCameraLandScape(getActivity())) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(ORIENTATIONS_LAND.get(Utils.getRotation(context)));
            Log.e("IMAGE", "preCreateCamera land "+Utils.getRotation(context));
        } else {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(ORIENTATIONS_PORT.get(Utils.getRotation(context)));
            Log.e("IMAGE", "preCreateCamera port "+Utils.getRotation(context));
        }
        //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (configure_preview)


    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC );
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    String path  = getVideoFile(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).getAbsolutePath();
    currentFile = path;
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);

    // END_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)

    // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

i had to comment this because apparently in a specific [device](http://www.qilive.com/sites/default/files/content/fiche_technique/pdf/fp-q.3778-qilive-tablet_10.1_black.pdf) i had for tests ( and i assume it happens on others ) i couldnt see the video preview and i got a MediaRecorder - “start failed: -19”

```
//        profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
//        profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;
```

**My problem**

When i set the

```
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
```

to

```
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
```

the camera doesnt seem to start the preview, and on the Log.e i get "E/Resolution: 1280 - 720", but from what i've seen on the specs of the [device](http://www.qilive.com/sites/default/files/content/fiche_technique/pdf/fp-q.3778-qilive-tablet_10.1_black.pdf), it should only go up to 640 - 480

Do i need to set some other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the quality you have to check if the camera supports that quality.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a nexus 6p device when setting the **QUALITY_HIGH** on the **MediaRecorder**.

I found the issue to the **setMaxDuration()** method call caused **MediaRecorder** to crash with a value that was too high.